# wxpython seems dead when doing with non-stopping events

Tags: python, thread-safety, wxpython, web-crawler

im writing a web crawler, using wxpython to display the real-time result. Assuming that there is only one button named `crawl` on the window. when i clicked the button, a new dialog will come out, and the TextCtrl on the new dialog will display the current url that is crawling.

The codes can be simplified as follows(just UI with `WebCrawler` thread on `OnDisplayClick` function):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import wx
class Main ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.Crawl = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Crawl", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.Crawl.SetDefault() 
        bSizer3.Add( self.Crawl, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Crawl.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDisplayClick )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def OnDisplayClick( self, event ):

            #Show the display window
        newDisplay = Display(self)
            newDisplay.show()

            ############################################################
            ##          start a multi-threading webcrawler            ##
            ############################################################

            web_crawler = WebCrawler(newDisplay.current_url)
            web_crawler.startCrawl()



class Display ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.cur_url = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Current_URL: ", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.cur_url.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer4.Add( self.cur_url, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.current_url = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer4.Add( self.current_url, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( bSizer4 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass
```

UI:

[image: Crawl]
[image: Display]

WebCrawler is a multi-thread crawler, i pass the TextCtrl(`current_url`) to the WebCrawler to let it display the current crawling url on the display window, but when i click on the crawl button, the interface seems dead, i guess it is because the multi-threading WebCrawler is running and the UI thread cannot get the opportunity to display the new window. i tried to write another two threads using threading.Thread, one is used to display the new window, one to WebCrawler, but i failed, the app often exited immediately, though it can display the window and do with the crawl threadings for some seconds, and sometimes it told me something like:

```
(python2.7:5231): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_iter: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(python2.7:5404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `object->ref_count > 0' failed
```

the two theads are as follows:

```
class UpdateThread(threading.Thread):

    """ WebCrawler thread """

    def __init__(self, webCrawl):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.webCrawl = webCrawl

    def run(self):
        self.webCrawl.start()

class CrawlShowThread(threading.Thread):

    """ Display thread """
    def __init__(self, crawl_display):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.crawl_display = crawl_display

    def run(self):
        self.crawl_display.Show()
```

then both start() at the OnCrawlClick() function. but just like what i have said above, the method doesnt work.

can anyone tell me what is the right way to do with such things? any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't allowed to access the GUI from a non-main thread. See [the documentation wiki on this](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui#Communicating_with_the_main_thread).

Comment: Great! the method referred to on the documentation solved the problem perfectly. `PostEvent` is a good solution. thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're running a long task and it's blocking the GUI's main event loop, so it's basically frozen. You need to put the crawler into a separate thread and use wxPython's threadsafe methods to update the GUI. See the [wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) or this [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/)